# Creating a contract for a UDP connection

Tags: c#, .net, communication

I'm developing a system in `C#` who consists in a desktop application running a UDP server and a `android` app and this app sends data (byte array) to be read by the desktop application with commands and parameters for these commands. The goal is to achieve the best possible performance.

With that in mind, I thought about using constants refering the commands and their parameters and use a `swich-case` to check the command when an message is received. I's this a good approach? there's anything that can be more effective?

```
public class ContractConstants
{
    #region COMMANDS

    public const sbyte MOUSE_MOVE_COMMAND = 0x1;
    public const sbyte MOUSE_CLICK_COMMAND = 0x2;

    #endregion


    #region PARAMETERS

    //mouse move
    public const sbyte MOUSE_MOVE_Y_COMMAND_UP = 0x11;
    public const sbyte MOUSE_MOVE_Y_COMMAND_DOWN = 0x12;
    public const sbyte MOUSE_MOVE_X_COMMAND_RIGHT = 0x13;
    public const sbyte MOUSE_MOVE_X_COMMAND_LEFT = 0x14;

    //mouse click
    public const sbyte MOUSE_CLICK_COMMAND_SINGLE = 0x21;
    public const sbyte MOUSE_CLICK_COMMAND_DOUBLE = 0x22;

    #endregion
} 


protected override void OnReceived(EndPoint endpoint, byte[] buffer, long offset, long size)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incoming: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, (int)offset, (int)size));


    switch ((sbyte)buffer[0])
    {
        case ContractConstants.MOUSE_MOVE_COMMAND:
            //logic here
            break;
        case ContractConstants.MOUSE_CLICK_COMMAND:
            //logic here
            break;
    }

    // Echo the message back to the sender
    SendAsync(endpoint, buffer, 0, size);
}
```

Comment: Depends on how you define "good."

Answer (score 3):

Using the first byte (or bytes) of a raw data stream as an indicator for the type of the following data is pretty simple and straightforward, it is a standard approach which is used successfully since several decades in different situations.

Note the performance of this system will mostly be affected by the number of bytes transferred over the network, and the frequency of the commands issued. The implementation details of the code which decodes the commands will be mostly irrelevant on most contemporary CPUs (regardless whether it is a desktop CPU or a smartphone CPU). The decoding time will likely be only a very small fraction of the time required for the network transfer, so microoptimizing the decoder will usually be a waste of time.

Hence, focus on

- keeping the code clean and maintainable
- designing your protocol to keep the total number of bytes for a command small, and for issuing not more commands than necessary (still you will need to balance this with a certain extendability)

At the current stage of your design, from what we can see, both of these goals are most probably fulfilled, and you should not overthink this for now. However, when your code grows and contains not just ~50 lines, but 5000 or more, then will be the time to rethink and maybe refactor it.